# Make [watchos] primary tag, with [watch-os] and [watch-os-2] merged into it

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, synonym-request, tag-synonym-process

Currently, there are two tags and a synonym directly related to the watchOS operating system, [watch-os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watch-os), [watch-os-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watch-os-2), and the [watchos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchos) tag which is currently a synonym. In addition, there are [watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchkit) and [apple-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) tags, which are conceptual parallels to [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) and [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone).

The most important suggestion here is that [watch-os-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watch-os-2) be made a synonym of whichever tag becomes the primary watchOS tag. There are important developer differences between the two operating systems, but those differences are really between the APIs offered in WatchKit 1 and WatchKit 2 rather than being about the operating system as distinct from that API, and it is not the API-specific tag that is versioned.

Additionally, I recommend that [watchos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchos) be made the primary tag for the operating system. The operating system for the Apple Watch is called "watchOS", with a lowercase w and no space. Therefore, while there is a general preference for hyphens in multi-word tags, this is not actually a multi-word term that is being tagged. Additionally, the direct parallels in iPhone and Mac operating systems are tagged [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/osx), rather than the possible hyphenated alternatives, so the non-hyphenated version should be preferred for consistency.

Most of the watchOS related questions are really about [watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchkit), which is the developer API for watchOS. That tag is also active. Arguably, we should just have a [watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchkit) tag and merge all of the others into it. However, this logic has not been applied to merging [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) into [cocoa-touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cocoa-touch) (which correctly should be hyphenated).

If we are going to have a watchOS specific tag, other than [watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchkit), I recommend that it should be [watchos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchos) for consistency.

Comment: While I agree that `watchOS` should be the primary tag, I don't believe that `watchOS2`, `watchOS3`, etc., should be synonyms of `watchOS`. It would make it difficult to find or filter questions by OS version.

Comment: Also would not want to merge any other tags into `watchKit`.  There are plenty of questions that have *nothing* to do with the user interface, and everything to do with `WatchConnectivity`, complications, the watch's `HealthKit` store, etc.

Answer (score 1):

**watchOS** / all operating system versions

- I agree that (*unhyphenated*) [watchos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchos) should be the primary tag for any version of the Apple Watch OS. Any new questions would almost never be about WatchKit 1.
- I don't agree that version-specific OS tags should be synonyms of `watchOS`.

  It's common to want to search/filter specifically by version, either for the purpose of ignoring older/incompatible answers, or finding unanswered questions related to the newer OS.

  For comparison, tags like [ios8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios8) and [ios9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios9) are ***not*** synonyms of [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). We should endeavor to be consistent across platforms.

**apple-watch** / hardware

- [apple-watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple-watch) should continue to be a distinct tag, as there are a number of questions about the actual watch itself, such as sensors.

  *Unfortunately, it does get misused for software questions, despite its usage guidance.*

**watchkit** / user interface framework

- [watchkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/watchkit) should also continue to be distinct, as it is the watch's UI framework (just as [uikit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uikit) is separate from [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios)).

  Many watchOS questions *aren't* about `watchKit` itself, but are about other frameworks such as `WatchConnectivity`, `ClockKit`, or `HealthKit`. Those frameworks have little or nothing to do with interface objects or controllers, and require their own tags.

  We shouldn't merge other watchOS frameworks into `watchKit`.